# Can the Resistance Fighters use the fail card?

Tags: the-resistance

In the board game The Resistance are two factions, Resistance fighters and Spies.
Me and my friends had some debate if the Resistance fighters can actually use the Fail mission Card.

My stand is yes, the resistance fighters can also use the fail card, because I didn't see in the rule book that they can't use the fail card.

The question here is, can the good guys use the fail card whether he has a reason to use it or not?

**Edit**
based on the rulebook it is stated that

> The Resistance Operatives **must** select the Mission Success card; Spies may select either the Mission Success or Mission Fail card.

the question is, does the must is just only a Highly recommended move? or a compulsory move? based on the dictionaries i have checked **Must** is used in different ways.

**Edit**

So most of the suggestions in the answers pertains to "The resistance cant use the fail card because they have no objective to do it so."

That might be true to the plain The Resistance, but please mind that there are other modules/expansion packs in the Resistance that can give the Resistance an objective to fail a mission,

one example would be **The reverser module** wherein in this module the reverser (resistance or spy) can reverse the output of the mission, if resistance member already know who is the resistance reverser they can talk to each other like, "Hey reverser, pick the reverse card and ill pick a fail card so that we are sure that in this round we will win even though we get other spy in the mission group".

That is the main reason why i'm asking if the resistance can use the fail card. obviously in this expansion the good guy has already a reason to fail a mission., they can also fail the mission if he thinks that there is a reverser spy in the group and reversed the outcome of the game thinking that all of the resistance would vote success.

Comment: Question has been answered below that they can not.  However I'm interesting to know what reason they would ever have for failing a mission?

Comment: You could imagine someone thinking "X is on this mission, and I'm sure he's a spy.  By playing the fail card, I will make it more likely that other people think that he is a spy too."  It isn't a good strategy, which is probably part of the reason the rules explicitly disallow it.

Comment: I've read accounts of a few games where someone who missed this rule was playing as the Merlin role in Resistance: Avalon and dropped a fail into a mission with a spy on it, probably one that requires two fails.

Comment: Guys first of all "Must" does not mean they can only use Success, must pertains to a word that they should use the Success in order to win, because failing a mission as a resistance is non-sense right? but in a reverser module you can talk to a good reverser so that the outcome of the game can be predicted like, "hey im a good guy reverse this round and ill fail this mission so we win", like that, you can check the uses in must here http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must

Comment: @bwarner it is not explicitly disallowed it but it was highly recommended by the rule book. must is not equal to "Only" or other compulsory words, must is used to show what is highly or likely to be done

Comment: tagging @MildlyPerilous

Comment: What purpose would a resistance member get from playing a fail card? All that would happen is you would confuse other resistance members and cause the game to be lost.

Comment: @JoeW - Funny story - One game I've played one of the resistance members did precisely this. His rationale was that he knew that one of the others on the mission was a spy, so he played a spy card to shine suspicion on him. He was in fact correct and the gambit played off, the resistance won the game.

Comment: @JoeW as i have explained above in the reverser module where in a reverser can reverse the outcome of a mission, a resistance member can then talk to a resistance member reverser (if he already know) so that the outcome of the game can be predicted like,. "hey reverser reverse this round and ill fail so that we will win"

Comment: Once again - in casual language, it's fine to say "I must call my sister" to mean "It would be a really good idea to call my sister" (although even in that context it makes you sound like a member of the British Royal family). However, in the context of a rulebook, particularly in the way the sentence itself is worded, "must" is to be read as an imperative. You can add in the contrast of the fact that the Spy *may* do something else. It's not a "you have to do this or you will lose", it's "you do not have an option to do otherwise".

Comment: @ConMan so you do say that even in the reverser module good guys should not use the fail card even though they have the reason to fail a mission?

Comment: Yes. The rule as worded is completely unambiguous. It's not a case of "Resistance has no reason to", it's a case of "Resistance is not allowed to". If it was allowed, then the rule would state "Resistance and Spies may both use either Success or Fail, but Resistance probably shouldn't" or words to that effect.

Comment: Agree with the other people here. "Must" in the context of rules means exactly that. It does not mean should or may or can choose to. Must means must. As for the reverser module, that's for a situation where you have foolishly given the power to a spy and they screw you over in a late game hail Mary where you think you've won.

Comment: If you look closely at the cards Success has both the blue (good) and red (bad) symbols, but Fail only has the red symbol.

Comment: Well if you want to get all word-smithy, it is **highly recommended** that you comply with the commonly used definition of **must** or you will probably not be invited back to play many games :)

Comment: When "must" means "really should", it's always referring to a future event, and its use is often followed by a "but" clause. Rules tell you what you must do immediately, where "must" always indicates a requirement. Both by the English language and by gaming jargon, the members of the resistance must vote to succeed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From the [rulebook:](http://www.boardgameguys.ie/sites/bggnew/files/The_Resistance_rules_english.pdf)

> Note: The Resistance Operatives **must** select the Mission Success card; Spies may
>   select *either* the Mission Success or Mission Fail card.

Further confirmation for rules lawyers

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/585119/resistance-must-select-mission-success-card-constr

https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/1467743/mistakenly-failing-mission

Comment: yigiter, Must does not mean they can only use Success  http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/must

Comment: i highly doubt about this answer unless you can clear me what is the meaning of MUST, based on the dictionary must is used to give a highly recommended action not a compulsory one.

Comment: If they meant "should" they would say "should".  "Must" in a rules document is clearly compulsory.  If you want to debate that, I'd suggest taking it to the English Language site.

Comment: In the context of stating rules, "must" is a directive. That section isn't talking about strategy, it's saying that Resistance *must* play success, Spies *may* play either.

Comment: @bwarner already posted at the English Language site, the thing is if the resistance can only use the Success card they should have stated it like that

Comment: please see my another edit also yigiter.

Comment: @User They did state it like that.  You are literally the only person I have ever met that reads "must" in a rules document as optional.

Comment: User6675636b20796f7521  @bwarner, ConMan, Daniel Lim, and Tom77 are all correct and you are wrong.  Repeating the same thing multiple times does not make you correct.

If you do not believe us, try interpreting "must" as "highly recommended" in literally any game and see how the other players react.  For example, in volleyball a team MUST use a maximum of three hits to return the ball.  (source: wikipedia).  They ARE NOT ALLOWED to use 10 hits and then claim it was legal and 3 was only the highly recommended maximum.

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 I have added my own answer which explains why all dictionary definitions of **must** are not applicable to games in general and I recommend that you read it to understand why you are incorrect in this line of thought.

Answer (score 10):

In board game rules **must** means it is compsulory, and **may** means they don't have to, but the option is open to them.

The rules are very clear for this particular issue, genuine resistance members are not allowed to play fail cards.

Answer (score 3):

I posted a shorter version of this as a comment but am also writing an answer which allows for more details.

As others have stated, **must** in the context of games refers to a mandatory action or restriction.  This includes many types of games, including board games, card games, and sports.  If you don't believe, try interpreting **must** as "highly recommended but not required" in other games and see how the other players react.  For example:

[Volleyball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volleyball#Rules_of_the_game) includes the rule:

> The opposing team **must** use a combination of no more than three
>   contacts with the volleyball to return the ball to the opponent's side
>   of the net.

This means a team IS NOT ALLOWED to use 10 hits, claiming it was legal and 3 was only the highly recommended maximum.

[Poker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betting_in_poker) includes the rule:

> Under normal circumstances, all other players still in the pot **must**
>   either call the full amount of the bet or raise if they wish remain
>   in, the only exceptions being when a player does not have sufficient
>   stake remaining to call the full amount of the bet (in which case they
>   may either call with their remaining stake to go "all-in" or fold) or
>   when the player is already all-in.

This means that a player IS NOT ALLOWED to remain in the hand without matching the bet, claiming that it is only highly recommended to match the bet but legal not to do so.

A nearly infinite number of additional examples exist.

Comment: For the record i am **ACCEPTING** the answers of the others, im implying my own thinking for the sake of argument and discussion, this is question and answer site not a Yes No question Site. **FYI** PS. I Believe all of you and im not repeating myself so that i would be correct, i AM looking for any possible answers given to different circumstances. **OK?**

Answer (score -1):

No! Never! Who is the Resistance should ALWAYS play the success card!

If someone from the Resistance mistakenly threw a Fail, the game loses all its logic and it is completely impossible to know who is who.

You should highlight this rule a lot when explaining the game to newbies!

Comment: The rules have already been quoted, and **require** Resistance Fighters to play *Success* cards, by saying they **must** do so. The idea that they "should" suggests that they could also do otherwise.